# Recreate a campaign with original id

Tags: data-import-wizard, undelete

[image]I deleted a couple of campaigns because I didn't need them or their contents.  I am now trying to undelete a Contact record that was a campaign member of the deleted campaign.  I think the undelete is failing because it is trying to create a campaign member with a campaign id that no longer exists.  I have a backup of the campaign when it existed & have its id.  Is there a way to recreate the campaign with the original id.  I am working with Salesforce Professional.  The only way I know to import data is via the Data Import Wizard.  I don't see a way to import campaigns.  I don't know why.  Thoughts on how to handle this problem?  Ultimately, I need to undelete a Contact.  I think the campaign member records without a valid campaign is the problem (or at least part of the problem).

Comment: To answer the top question: no, you cannot recreate a record with the exact same Id. They are generated by the system and can't be set on creation of a record. Second, the Campaign Member record would not be revived while undeleting the Contact since the Campaign itself does not exist, and this should not cause the undelete to fail. Unfortunately, though, this is as far as we can go with the information given. How did you try to restore the Contact? What error(s) did you get?

Comment: To undelete the contact record, I switch to Classic and go to the Recycle Bin.  I have no problem undeleting other Contact records.  I just put an image of the error in my question.  Nothing has changed with the schema since the record was deleted a few days ago.

Comment: Do you have a Unique Index field on your Contact object? That's the only reason I can think of in Professional Edition that could cause this problem.

Comment: I removed all the unique index fields on my Contact object. I still cannot undelete the Contact record.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Debug Logs (Your Name > Developer Console) to see what the underlying error is? Have you tried contacting support? I can tell you that the missing campaign isn't the problem, but unfortunately I don't know what it *could* be, either, not without more information.

Comment: I turned on debug & reviewed the debug log.  I am not seeing an error message.  I have a case open with Salesforce technical support.  They are puzzled at the moment.